# Identify requests made by other extensions?

Tags: security, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like my extension to be able to listen for requests made by other extensions. I don't control the server they are speaking to- it's more I want to just log when they make requests, to help identify things like [this.](https://mig5.net/content/awesome-screenshot-and-niki-bot)

I have tested with the [chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) event, but the only way I see a way to get info on where the request came from is through the tabId property. This property is -1 for a request made by an extension background page though.

[image]

I have tested by having my own extension make a request every 5 seconds, and then I can see the event being fired, but there is not enough information to identify the request as coming from any particular extension.

Is there something I am missing, or another way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension cannot easily and reliably identify requests made by other extensions, because an extension could use a content script to perform a request, which is indistinguishable from a request that is made by the page where the content script is inserted.

If an extension has not declared the permissions to access a specific website, the request header will contain the `Origin: chrome-extension://[extensionid]/...` request header. This value could be spoofed by an extension on purpose, if wanted though. Furthermore, it is quite rare for an extension to perform a cross-origin request without having the right permissions, because the request would only be accepted if the server accepts the cross-origin request by CORS.

If you really want to identify requests made by other extensions, then you could use the remote debugging protocol via the [`chrome.debugger`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API to get notified of network requests. The remote debugging protocol is documented at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol, and the relevant part of the networking messages is available at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/network.

Comment: Ah, good point about content scripts. For my purposes though I am happy to only capture requests made by background pages- would that change your answer?
That remote debugger looks promising, I didn't know that existed. I need to read up on it! Does it rely on having the devtools opened by the user before I can use it?

Comment: Actually, reading it, do I not need to supply a tabId that is the target for routing commands to? Extension background pages don't have a tab.

Comment: @user3806049 You can specify an extension ID (see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#type-Debuggee) In order to debug other extensions using `chrome.debugger`, Chrome must be started with the `--silent-debugger-extension-api` flag. And no, you cannot detect requests coming from the background page of another extension using the webRequest API.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will do some testing with that API, though I think requiring that flag will probably make it a non-runner for just plain use in an extension. Thanks!